# Present Perfect Simple or Present Perfect Progessive?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> How long _______ there? (work/you)

Which tense to use. A) Present Perfect Simple, or B) Present Perfect Progressive?

> A) How long have you worked there?
>   B) How long have you been working there?

Comment: You need to provide some argument of your own. Also, this question has been answered tons of times here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the sentences, but meanings will be different

> How long have you worked there?

This sentence implies you are asking somebody a question who has quit his job that he did there(at some place)

> How long have you been working there?

This sentence implies you are asking somebody a question who is still doing his job that he does there(at some place)

Comment: If the statement was "You work for the bank, right? How long _____ 
there? (work/you)"?

Comment: How long have you been working would be correct, because you still work with the bank.

Comment: @KshitijSingh should *how long have you worked there?* necessarily imply that I've quit the job?

Comment: Too bad this answer has been accepted. As @AndrewT mentions, it gives erroneous guidance. Jed: _Where do you work?_ Ted: _I work at the bank_. Jed: _How long have you worked there?_ My guess is that Ted would say, “Ten years,” not, “Learn some better grammar. I still work there.” Moreover, if I knew someone had quit their job, my question would be: _How long **had** you worked there?_

Comment: "How long did you work there?" is also possible if someone doesn't work there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you added in a comment, they mean exactly the same thing. I would prefer the shorter and simpler one as a general rule, but that is just personal style.